# 1920’s 2 story brick home sagging ceilings down the middle

Tags: ceiling, floor

I am not sure if I should sister joists for both the 1st floor ceiling and then the second story floor or can I jack up just the 1st floor ceiling and take care of it that way. Its a hip roof with no walls in attic so it would only lift 1st floor ceiling, floor 2’s floor and walls and 2nd floor ceiling. Not worried about 2nd floor cracks in walls as they need fixed anyways. Any advice or knowledge passed would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Some added info.. the 1st floor had all the floors leveled, by sistering the joists, so I’m unable to jack from the basement. The ceiling sagged 2 1/2 inches on the load bearing wall running in the center of the house.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A bit more info (e.g. how, and how much, are the ceilings sagging) would help us here.

Comment: the 1st floor had all the floors leveled, by sistering the joists, so I’m unable to jack from the basement. The ceiling sagged 2 1/2 inches on the load bearing wall running in the center of the house.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm guessing you're going to need a structural engineer on-site to get an authoritative answer. But, maybe one of our pros will offer an opinion...